# jQuery datepicker within dynamic div

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

I have a form that contains field sets and has the ability to add a new section (clone of a previous field set). I can pick the dates for the original fields but when I add a new section the datepicker function does not generate.

My code and example are listed here -> http://jsbin.com/aqijuh/15

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have to call the `datepicker()` function on the newly added element

```
 document.getElementById("placeholder").appendChild(newFieldSet);
 $('input.date', newFieldSet).datepicker();
  window.lastClone = newFieldSet.id;
```

http://jsbin.com/aqijuh/17/edit

Comment: could it depend on the browser I'm using?

Comment: @PlatiNUM no it shouldn't depend on the browser, to me it's working both in firefox and chrome

Comment: Ok. Something was going wrong in IE. But now it works. Thanks!